# Delete duplicates excluding columns

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I am trying to delete duplicates from an internal table, comparing all columns excluding some of them. Obviously I can list all the columns that I want to compare using COMPARING, but this would not look good in code.

So let's say there are 100 columns and I want to exclude from the comparing 2.

How can I achieve that with a smart way?

Comment: Please clarify why it would "not look good". What do you think does "not look good". Anyway, you need to indicate all 100 columns, so what is the issue with that? Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DELETE ADJUSTMENT DUPLICATES](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapdelete_duplicates.htm) operator, there you can define which columns you compare. You'll just have to sort the itab before this operation.